# adding code to bpf _kernel.c file for uprobe SEC routines (libbpf +c)

Tags: c, ebpf, bpf, libbpf, uprobe

I am trying function count for given executable and pattern. trying
to explore latest introduced API bpf_program__attach_uprobe_multi,
couldn't find example for the same.
below code failing with invalid argument.
added prints in libbpf code, looks like path, pattern, variable taken properly
ibbpf: func pattern op_* path /data/expr/operations from libbps cnt 2
libbpf: offsets 4521  4538

**libbpf: prog 'test_uprobe': failed to attach multi-uprobe: Invalid argument**

Not sure what am i missing here.

Below is hardcode in kernel bpf code.

```
`// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 OR BSD-3-Clause
`int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        size_t offset1;
        size_t offset2;
        int err, i;
        char filename[256];
        pid_t pid;
        struct bpf_object *obj = NULL;
        struct bpf_program *prog[2];
        static struct bpf_link *bpflinks[2];
        static struct bpf_link *ubpflinks[2];

        if (argc < 2) {
                printf("Error return \n");
                return 0;
        }
        pid = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        snprintf(filename, 256, "/proc/%d/exe", pid);
       

        offset1 = get_elf_func_offset("/data/expr/operations", "op_add");
        offset2 = get_elf_func_offset("/data/expr/operations", "op_sub");
       
        snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s.bpf.o", argv[0]);
        obj = bpf_object__open_file(filename, NULL);
        if (libbpf_get_error(obj)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: opening BPF object file failed\n");
                obj = NULL;
                goto cleanup;
        }
    
          /* load BPF program */
        if (bpf_object__load(obj)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: loading BPF object file failed\n");
                goto cleanup;
        }
        prog[0] = bpf_object__find_program_by_name(obj, "handle_uprobe_ref_ctr");
       // prog[1] = bpf_object__find_program_by_name(obj, "handle_uretprobe_ref_ctr");

        ubpflinks[0] =
                bpf_program__attach_uprobe(prog[0], false /* not uretprobe */,
                                pid, "/data/expr/operations" , offset1);
        if (!ubpflinks[0])
                printf("failed at link0\n");

        ubpflinks[1] =
                bpf_program__attach_uprobe(prog[0], false /* not uretprobe */,
                                pid, "/data/expr/operations" , offset2);
        if (!ubpflinks[1])
                printf("failed at link1\n");
//      bpflinks[0] = bpf_program__attach(prog[0]);  // do we need to attach already probes attached
      


        getchar();
cleanup:
        bpf_link__destroy(ubpflinks[0]);
        bpf_link__destroy(ubpflinks[1]);
        return -err;
}


char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";

SEC("uprobe")
int handle_uprobe_ref_ctr(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    
   const char fmt_str[] = "function fp %lld ip %lld\n";
   bpf_trace_printk(fmt_str, sizeof(fmt_str), (void *)PT_REGS_FP(ctx));

        return 0;
}

SEC("uretprobe")
int handle_uretprobe_ref_ctr(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
        bpf_printk("handle_uretprobe_ref_ctr \n");
        return 0;
}
`
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the blocker is. What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: updated with code , trying to explore usecase  bpf_program__attach_uprobe_multi , program failed with invalid argument.  please let me know if there some example for the same @pchaigno

Comment: seems like uprobe multi doesn't have kernel support yet. there is patch https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/20230809083440.3209381-1-jolsa@kernel.org/T/ , not sure its merged

Comment: Since product we support is starting with kernel 5.0 meaning tool was written in bcc , plan is to move to libbpf.  we need to support customers with little older kernels too.how do we achieve above uprobe multi functionality in older kernels. is it possible with bpf_program__attach_uprobe,  @pchaigno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uprobe multi-attach support has been [merged in bpf-next](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bpf/bpf-next.git/commit/?id=c5487f8d91868eeab17a59cf4d164ea113f90252), but hasn't been released yet. I'd expect it to make it into Linux v6.6.

For older kernels, you will have to rely on `bpf_program__attach_uprobe`:

```
LIBBPF_API struct bpf_link * bpf_program__attach_uprobe (const struct bpf_program *prog, bool retprobe, pid_t pid, const char *binary_path, size_t func_offset)
```

Note the `bpf_program__attach_uprobe_multi` function from libbpf also hasn't been released yet. [Libbpf v1.2.2](https://libbpf.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.2/api.html) only has `bpf_program__attach_uprobe`.

Comment: thanks for quick response @pchaigno , got clarity now , will play around with bpf_program__attach_uprobe

Comment: modified question with bpf_program__attach_uprobe sample , tried this to achieve bpf_program__attach_uprobe_multi , but only one function trigging the uprobe handler.  Above example both op_add, op_sub attached to single handler . is there boilerplate code to start with. @pchaigno  ( i understand one uses perf_event other mult version uses  uprobe_register mechanisrm)

Comment: Please don't edit the question after it was answered. That is very confusing for anyone who is going through the same questions. It would be best to open a new question for `bpf_program__attach_uprobe` and I'm happy to take a look. A new question will also give you more visibility (others may know the answer).

Comment: sure, soryy my bad

Comment: posted as new question ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76999758/use-bpf-program-attach-uprobe-api-multiple-times-with-the-same-program-instan@pchaigno

Comment: bpf_program__attach_uprobe works fine to attach multiple target functions but helper routines for parsing lib/executable, function pattern and offsets is not exposed to user in libbpf.   bpf_program__attach_uprobe_multi uses most of the helpers  like  resolve_full_path, elf_resolve_pattern_offsets,  elf_resolve_syms_offsets. (code is LGPL-2.1 OR BSD-2-Clause), is it possible to pickup code for commercial use or need to rollout our own. @pchaigno